# Lengths of segments on unit circle have $L_1\cdot L_2...L_n>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $z_1,...,z_n$ be $n$ given points on the unit circle. For a given $z$ on the unit circle, draw a line segment from $z$ to each $z_k$. Let $L_k$ denote the length of the line segment connecting $z$ and $z_k$. Prove that there is a location for $z$ on the unit circle so that $L_1\cdot L_2\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot L_n>1$.

Based on the current section, I assume that complex series (Laurent/Power) must be used in some respect. However, I do not no where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the maximum modulus principle given $|f(0)| = 1$

$$f(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)$$